# WAP Push atop FLASH SMS

Tags: sms, mobile-phones, nokia, wap

I want to send a WAP Push SI, but I want the message to look like an alert - like FLASH SMS. I've tried to make the SMS carrying the WAP data a FLASH SMS, but the it seems the phone can't handle it. I tried it on a Nokia 6230i.

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing, or phones in general won't handle **WAP over FLASH SMS** as I expected?

*Can you suggest another solution for improving the user-experience with WAP PUSH, meaning to make it appear as an alert?*

Thanks,
Asaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although theoretically possible I think phones in general are unable to handle this combination.

You'll have to stick with either flash or push messages. I don't think there's any way you can improve the user experience with wap push, other than making sure the message and the content of the wap page you push is clear and concise. Is wap push messages really such a bad user experience that they need this improvement? I find them to be easy to use and they aren't stored in the SMS inbox so in that sense they "dissappear" just like the flash sms.

You could send one flash sms informing the user that he is about to receieve a link and then send the push message, but depending on your application that might just make the user experience worse..

Comment: WAP Push messages are not such bad experience, but at least on Nokia they lead the user to the Service Inbox, where they have to click again to go to content. The Service Inbox is something the user doesn't expect, and that extra click is really uncalled for. Bad UX on Nokia's part.